# Migrate app to ios11 for Iphone X

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

I need to update my app and make it look good on the iphone X. I've seen a couple of answers on stackoverflow and on the internet regarding the new safe area option (Use Safe Area Layout Guides).
According to what I've read the app should adapt automatically using autolayout as well but what I've got is this:

[image]

If I start a new project it all works fine. The project is quite big, so starting all over again is not an option. What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem, and in my case, the problem was that my app didn't have a Launch Screen.storyboard, it was using a image as launcher. So adding a new Launch Screen.storyboard and selecting that one fixed it, maybe the rest of the app takes some settings from that Launch Screen.storyboard